# How do I upgrade to the latest Grub 2.00?

Tags: installation, grub2, compiling, bootloader, install-from-source

According to [this link](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2012-06/msg00093.html), GRUB 2.00 has just been released. How can one upgrade to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ## [Danger!](https://askubuntu.com/a/157837/58612)
>
> GRUB is your *bootloader*  -- the first piece of software to start after you switch on your computer, and responsible for loading the operating system.
>   **Grub 2.00 has not been tested by Ubuntu and any problems may render your system *unbootable*--including Windows if dual-boot**--and will require a LiveCD/LiveUSB and time to fix.
>
> Unless you simply want to experiment, **it is highly recommended to wait for Grub 2.00 to officially make its way into Ubuntu** (or at least until 2.00 shows up in Debian Sid or the Quantal alphas!)
>
> <sup>That said, Linux/FOSS is about freedom, and if you get the gun, I'll teach you how to shoot! :)</sup>

---

#### If you still want to install Grub 2.00 after the warnings above:

You'll have to build it from source. Open the terminal and type/paste:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep grub2
wget -O- ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grub/grub-2.00.tar.xz | tar -xJ
cd grub-2.00
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

- Now, you need to install the new Grub to **where your existing Grub is**. If you don't know where or how to find out, quit now!

  - If you have a dual-boot system, be especially careful about whether you should install to the *disk* or to the *partition!*
  - Replace *sdq* as appropriate:

    ```
    sudo grub-install /dev/sdq
    ```
  - Run `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot, and...it's slightly different...

  [image]
- Advanced Options gives us the reassuring....

  [image]
- But "GNU/Linux" *seems to* work anyway...

  [image]

---

#### Uninstall?

No guarantees, but `sudo apt-get --reinstall install grub2` *should* overwrite Grub 2.00 with the official 1.99x version.

Comment: Read your warnings, and got that overwhelming feeling that I should not try this. ;) Well, I will wait as you mentioned. I'll accept the answer and upvote since this answers the question for those daring souls who want to try this. :)